# Deploying the WPF app.config file with setup project

Tags: wpf, deployment, app-config

This has been bothering me for two days now. I have a WPF application which has a database and focusses on handwriting recognition. Thus, I have a connection string in the app.config file, along with startup parameters for when the app starts - this is to enable version2 runtime otherwise the handwriting recognition doesnt work. Everything works perfectly when debugging...

I created an install with the Visual Studio Setup Wizard and installed the application. The installation went fine, but now **everytime I try to use the app.config file, a NullReference is thrown.**

So I would like to know: 
Should I set the app.config file as a resource or embedded resource, or keep it content? 
Why can the app successfully read the contents of the app.config file when debugging, but once installed it crashes when retrieving the connectionstring property? 
When creating the install, is there some setting that I should perform so that the app.config file can be used in the code? (Cause the app.config file is the the program files directory).

So now, if I hardcode the connectionstring (in a variable) everything works fine, but the handwriting recognition doesnt work because the app.config file isn't being used it seems.

I am kind of pressed for time, so any help would be deeply appreciated.

PS: Just for the sake of it, here is the app.config file's contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name ="conString" connectionString="server=ServerName;database=dbname;Integrated Security='true'"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app.config` file is autogenerated from the `settings` (in Visual Studio under Properties / Settings.settings). If this connection string is in the settings, you'll be able to access it via:

`var conString = Settings.Default.conString;`

It will also be compiled into the project and only be overridden by the `app.config` file if it's is available.

Also the `app.config` file has to be a file in the same folder as the executable `.exe` file, and has to have the same name. For example, if it's `myprogram.exe`, the `myprogram.config` file should be in the same directory.